# Refill multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Does somebody knows how I can refill this kind of array? I need to insert some values instead of the 0. 
I make two loop, one for creating the array structure, and the another for filling the array, but when I want to file, I get an error "offset 0".

The values are integer numbers.

And I have a `for` loop:

```
$lista[$medio]  = Array();
for ($count=1; $count<=53; $count++) {      
    $lista[$medio][$count]  = 0;
}
for ($j = 1; $j <= $counter ; $j++) {    
    $f = $d[0]['f'];
    $xn= $d[0]['d'];
    $xww= explode("/",$xn);
    $kw = $xww[0];
   // Here I'm filling the list, I need the values from $f to be inserted instead of the 0 from the array. I think this is the correct way to do that:
    $lista[$medio][intval($kw)]+= $f;   
    print_r($lista);
}
```

// But I get "offset 0" error

```
Array
(
    [ge] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [15] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [18] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [20] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 0
            [24] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [29] => 0
            [30] => 0
            [31] => 0
            [32] => 0
            [33] => 0
            [34] => 0
            [35] => 0
            [36] => 0
            [37] => 0
            [38] => 0
            [39] => 0
            [40] => 0
            [41] => 0
            [42] => 0
            [43] => 0
            [44] => 0
            [45] => 0
            [46] => 0
            [47] => 0
            [48] => 0
            [49] => 0
            [50] => 0
            [51] => 0
            [52] => 0
            [53] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: We don't have $d and $x here.. How do they look?

Comment: Nor do we have $medio. We cannot try your code, and if I understand you correctly I think the error occurs somewhere else? "want to file"?

Comment: Sorry guys, i edited just now!.$lista[$medio][intval($kw)]+= $f;  this is $kw this variable have inside integer numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use PHP function **array_fill_key**

### http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-fill-keys.php

### http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-fill.php

Example from PHP:

```
<?php
$keys = array('foo', 5, 10, 'bar');
$a = array_fill_keys($keys, 'Banane');
print_r($a);
?>
```

I hope works for you!